# How to validate user answer in a multiple choice question using Siri voice commands

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I need to build a quiz type application using Siri. 
Here, let us consider,  my application have only one question along with multiple choices as answers.
Now with the Siri voice commands, I need to load that question along with choices onto the  Label/ textview.
Once that question gets loaded onto the Lable/textview, this question should be spoken by Siri.
Now the user can choose his/her answer either a or b or c or d using their voice command.
Then Siri should validate the user's input with the correct answer. 
If its correct, Siri should say”correct answer”. Otherwise It should say “wrong answer. The correct answer is and so on..”

I have implemented half part of my requirements, Using Siri shortcuts, I can able to  load the question onto a Label and Siri can speak that question.

for your reference, please find my code below.

In `ViewController.swift` file I have implemented below code,

```
Public fund createShortcutForloadingQuestion(){

  let userAct = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.organization.QuizSpeakingApp.loadQuestion")
        userAct.title = "get the text from document"
        userAct.userInfo =  ["question" : "what is the capital of India?  \n a. Kolkata \n b. Mumbai, \n c. Bengaluru,\n d.  New Delhi"]
        userAct.isEligibleForSearch = true
        userAct.isEligibleForPrediction =  true
        userAct.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier("com.organization.QuizSpeakingApp.loadQuestion")
         textLbl.userActivity = userAct
        userAct.becomeCurrent()
         displayTextOnLabel()
}



public func displayTextOnLabel() {
     textLbl.text = “what is the capital of India?  \n a. Kolkata \n b. Mumbai, \n c. Bengaluru,\n d.  New Delhi.”
    }
```

To speak the loaded question I have implemented the code like below,

```
 public func speakTheQuestion(){
    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textLbl.text ?? "Label Doesnt have any text")
    speechUtterance.rate = 0.5
    speechUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
    speechUtterance.volume = 1.0
    speechUtterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0.005
    speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
    }
```

Now to create a shortcut for loading the question and to speak the loaded question,
I have implemented the below method in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
 let viewController = window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
        viewController.displayTextOnLabel()
        viewController.speakTheQuestion()
        return true
    }
```

With the above implementation I can able to load the question and spoken it by Siri.

Now, Anyone can help me how to take user answer with voice command, and how to validate their answer with the correct answer and how to give update about his answer with Siri?

Thanks in andvance.

Answer (score -1):

as of now Sirikit handle only a specific domains and intents.

[More about SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit?language=objc)

For your use case I would suggest you to use **SpeechKit**. Speechkit take voice as input and convert it to text. It has accuracy and works amazingly. You can ask question to user and then starts speech recognition using speechKit and read user's reply.

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

        var isFinal = false

        if result != nil {
            let string = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.textView.text = string
            if((string?.elementsEqual("A"))! || (string?.elementsEqual("Option A"))!)
            {
                //user said option A is correct, perform your action
            }
            else if((string?.elementsEqual("B"))! || (string?.elementsEqual("Option B"))!)
            {
                 //user said option B is correct, perform your action
            }
            //......
            isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!

        }

        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil

            self.microPhoneButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    })
```

[more about SpeechKit in iOS](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/)